# Very slow Sprockets in Rails 4 development environment: what's wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I've been banging my head over this for some time. Our project has grown to a reasonable size: approx. 250 JS files and 50 SASS files. Not too excessive, I would say. Still, Sprockets is taking a very long time to render all the assets. Even on simple page reloads, where I would expect to see some benefits of caching, it takes seconds to 10, 20, 30 and sometimes more seconds to serve all assets. And that's on a decent MacBook Pro with SSD.

Here's a flamegraph of one of the simplest pages: the login page. That takes about 12 seconds to load. The "real" application pages are much worse:

[image]

Setting `config.assets.debug = false` helps some, but at the same time, I would really love to keep it set to true for easier debugging.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to make this more workable?

Comment: What is the version of sprockets you are using?